# Python code gets stuck with AsyncIO tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import websockets
import cfscrape
import json

async def test():
    while True:
        for x in asyncio.all_tasks():
            print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    
async def connect():
    async with websockets.client.connect('SOMEURL') as ws:
        while True:
            print(await ws.recv())

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(test()), asyncio.create_task(connect())]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here, one function is supposed to connect to a websocket URI and print the data it receives, while the other function should, in parallel, print the active tasks, so they need to run concurrently. This code is not supposed to stop, since it receives data from a websocket server. The problem seems to be the function `test()`, since if i remove it, the code will run fine.

The problem with this is that, after starting the script from my console, it will get stuck after 2/3 seconds of running it, so after printing the active tasks for a bunch of seconds, it will stop. I'm not getting any error, but if i hit CTRL+C it will start running again for some seconds before being exited. Can anyone help me find what's wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is it getting stuck? Can you add some diagnostic info to your question?

Comment: Do you know if `websockets.client.connect('SOMEURL')` succeeds?

Comment: Yes. The websocket connection succeeds, since i see the data being printed

Comment: If you wrote your own test server can you include a minimal example of it in your question?

Comment: Isn't it awaiting indefinitely in ```print(await ws.recv())```? Try changing it to ```print(await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=5))``` and see if it raise timeout.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't raise a timeout

Comment: I wrote a server, based on the websocket docs, that serves 1000 messages and your program works fine for me. Your client ran fine for about two minutes, alternating between coroutines, till the server ran out of messages and closed the connection.  The only changes I made were to assign the `recv` message to a variable before printing and add a sleep to `connect` to allow `test` to run.  I think the problem must be server side. 
Here is what I used to test your client (it will go away in a week): [https://dpaste.com/BLQ3PW3UF](https://dpaste.com/BLQ3PW3UF)

Comment: @wwii Sorry for the late answer, i was in a hurry and didn't manage to read all the answers. Yes, i should have probably included the URI i was retrieving from my code, if you need it i can add that to the question, would be better than using a test server. I tried to run your code and it worked fine, without getting stuck, i don't understand what's wrong with mine. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: What happens if, after the while loop on connect(), you remove everything and only do a pass? I tried that, and that seems to cause the error i was talking about

Comment: @JayK23 Do you mean replace the _body_ of the loop with `pass` (`while True: pass`) or replace the whole loop with `pass`, i.e. remove the loop altogether and just leave `pass` in its place?

Comment: @wwii Just the body of the loop, so while True: pass. Also, you can try with this url, since you needed a server 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_5m'